# How to Update the Order-Items While Editing an Order on the WooCommerce Admin Order Screen

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic, hooks, admin

Is it possible to edit order item totals and custom fees in the woocommerce admin edit order screen? The only hook that I can find is `woocommerce_new_order_item`, but when I add/remove a product in the admin I need to adjust the custom order items totals (e.g. like deposit and delivery fees which are order line item fees).

For example, if I increase the quantity of a product (or add a different product to the order) in the edit order admin, I need to also increase the deposit amount on the order. I would also need to do the opposite, if I decrease quantity or remove a product from the order I'll need to decrease the deposit amount.

Is this doable?? What hooks should I be looking at? I've searched several forums and can't seem to find an answer.

Any help at all would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `woocommerce_order_before_calculate_totals` hook executes in the Edit Order admin screen when an item is changed or the 'recalculate' button is pressed. This allows you to loop through each item and fee in the order and edit as required. I have a fee called 'Deposit' which I update if it exists or I add if it doesn't.

```
function custom_order_before_calculate_totals($and_taxes, $order ) {
    // The loop to get the order items which are WC_Order_Item_Product objects since WC 3+
    // loop all products and calculate total deposit
    $total_deposit = 0;
    foreach( $order->get_items() as $item_id => $item ) {
        // get the WC_Product object
        $product = $item->get_product();

        // get the quantity
        $product_quantity = $item->get_quantity();

        // get the deposit amount
        $deposit = $product->get_attribute('deposit') * $product_quantity;

        // sum of deposits from all products
        $total_deposit += $deposit;
    }


    // update the Deposit fee if it exists
    $deposit_fee_exists = false;
    foreach( $order->get_fees() as $item_id => $item_fee ) {
        $fee_name = $item_fee->get_name();

        if ( $fee_name == 'Deposit' ) {
            $item_fee->set_tax_status('none'); // no tax on deposit
            $item_fee->set_total($total_deposit);
            $deposit_fee_exists = true;
            break;
        }
    }

    // if there isn't an existing deposit fee then add it
    if ( $total_deposit > 0 && !$deposit_fee_exists ) {
        // Get a new instance of the WC_Order_Item_Fee Object
        $item_fee = new WC_Order_Item_Fee();

        $item_fee->set_name( "Deposit" ); // Generic fee name
        $item_fee->set_amount( $total_deposit ); // Fee amount
        $item_fee->set_tax_status( 'none' ); // or 'none'
        $item_fee->set_total( $total_deposit ); // Fee amount

        // Add Fee item to the order
        $order->add_item( $item_fee );
    }
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_order_before_calculate_totals', "custom_order_before_calculate_totals", 10, 3);
```

Answer (score -1):

First of all, welcome to the community :)

When you add/remove an order item (e.g a product), WooCommerce uses an Ajax call to update the order.

### Adding a New Item to the Order

Adding a new item, would be done by `WC_AJAX::add_order_item()`. This method does the adding process and then fires [`woocommerce_ajax_order_items_added`](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/source-class-WC_AJAX.html#920) action hook. We can use that action to do some nasty stuff on the order!

For an example, if I want to add an order fee with total of 1000, when a product from product category 188 is added to the order, this would do the trick:

```
add_action('woocommerce_ajax_order_items_added', 'tst_update_order', 10, 2);

/**
 * @param \WC_Order_Item[]  $added_items
 * @param \WC_order $order
 */
function tst_update_order( $added_items, $order )
{
    foreach ( $added_items as $added_item ) {

        if ( 'line_item' === $added_item->get_type() ) {

            /** @var \WC_Order_Item_Product $added_item */
            $product = $added_item->get_product();
            $cat_ids = $product->get_category_ids();

            if ( in_array( 188, $cat_ids ) ) {
                $fee = new \WC_Order_Item_Fee();
                $fee->set_name('Order Fee');
                $fee->set_total('1000');
                $fee->save();
                $order->add_item($fee);
                $order->save();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Note:** There is another action [`woocommerce_ajax_add_order_item_meta`](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/source-class-WC_AJAX.html#914) which fires on updating every single order item. You may want to use that instead of looping through `$added_items`.

### Removing an existing Item from the Order

The corresponding method for removing an item from the current order is `WC_AJAX::remove_order_item()`. this method itself uses `wc_delete_order_item()` function to remove an order item. You may want to use the [`woocommerce_before_delete_order_item`](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/source-class-Abstract_WC_Order_Item_Type_Data_Store.html#101) action which is defined in this function to do your calculations and update the order.

Comment: Thanks. That led me in the right direction and I was able to solve using a different hook–woocommerce_order_before_calculate_totals–which executes when an item is changed or the 'recalculate' button is pressed. See answer below.